# If word in sentence in a particular column, match with another column?

Tags: shell, hash, cygwin

The text file is like this

```
Year, Name. Date, rating, username, tweet

2009, John, 02/03/09, positive, @johnnyboy, Bob is my best friend 
2010, Bob, 01/09/10, positive, @Bob, Bob is cool
2010, Bob, 05/03/10, positive, @Bob, This tweet shouldn't count
```

I want to be able to print all the dates that has a tweet with the word "Bob" in it (keeping in mind that username can be `@Bob`, which I don't want.

So the output should be

```
02/03/09
01/09/10
```

So far, my attempt is :

```
awk -F',' '{IGNORECASE = 1} {ARGC=1} $6=="Bob" {print $3}' Data.txt
```

I know the obvious mistake is that `==` will return only the dates where the tweet is just `Bob`, but my attempts have all be futile and that is the closest I could get to. Are there any other way to do this using `awk`?

Thank you

Comment: can you had little bit more content to your input in your question , may be I try with sed command

Comment: Using `csvkit` utilities: `csvgrep -c 6 -r Bob input.csv | csvcut -c 3`

Comment: @codeholic24 I edited it to give one more example. Thank you for trying out!

Comment: @Mateybro : please check I have answered , may be that will work for you. Required any further changes let me know. Will work around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tweet column may contain comma (,), you cannot use $6 directly :

```
awk -F',' '{IGNORECASE = 1} {ARGC=1} {col3=$3;$1=$2=$3=$4=$5=""; if (/Bob/) print col3}' Data.txt
```

1. `col3=$3` saves the third column in the variable `col3`
2. `$1=$2=$3=$4=$5=""` removed the first 5 columns
3. (/Bob/) compare the rest of columns against regular expression "Bob", because you could have a tweet like `Hi, Bob is my best friend`

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work. The word "Bob" will be contained in the column 6 which is a sentence. Thank you for your attempt though!

Comment: ahhh I'm so sorry! I didn't put the "/" in (/Bob/). You're absolutely correct and thank you so much! If you don't mind, could you please further explain some parts of the line? such as the purpose of {col3=$3;$1=$2.......} and also what does "/" do? I only understand "\" means the exact value.
I just started learning BASH and this will be extremely helpful in the future. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

**May be this will work**

**Command :**

```
grep -w 'Bob' abc.txt | awk -F',' '{print $3}'
```

**Output :**

```
02/03/09
01/09/10
```

if required any changes let me know will work around it

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! There is a slight issue (my apologies), I have edited my post further. Basically, @Bob (user) can also tweet a sentence that doesn't have the word 'Bob' in it, from the code given above, the date of that tweet will be part of the output, which is what I don't want. Thank you for your help though! I did not know that I could use awk and grep in the same pipeline!

Comment: @Mateybro : can you explain what actually tweet means

Comment: It's basically a sentence :) Thank you for your help though, I think I can get this!

Comment: @Mateybro : Cool